# hive date cast issue

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

Hi in my Hive table I have a column with the date values like this .

```
cl1
31102019000000
30112019000000
31122019000000
```

I have tried to convert the column values to date format like this

```
Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cl1,'yyyy/MM/dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from table1;
```

it prints NUll. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a string? Number? Are the dates 31st oct 2019 etc? Unix timestamps are the number of seconds since midnight on January 1 1970, they don't look like dates at all - treating these numbers as unix timestamps would see them somewhere around 2nd August 2955

Comment: It is stored as string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you have dates in dd-mm-yyyy but then posted data that doesn't have any hyphens in at all

Assuming 31102019000000 is 31-oct-2019 00:00:00

```
Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cl1,'ddMMyyyyHHmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from ...
```

Match the format string to the data..

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(REGEXP_REPLACE(cl1,'0+$',''),'ddMMyyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from table1;
```

but this would fail for years 2020,2010.
So the below query would be a better alternative

```
Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(cast(cl1/1000000 as bigint) as string),'ddMMyyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from table1;
```

Answer (score -1):

The UnixTimeStamp which you are trying to convert to date format is out of range. 
Your Time stamp corresponds to :

```
GMT: Saturday, August 2, 2955 1:43:20 AM
Your time zone: Saturday, August 2, 2955 5:43:20 AM GMT+04:00
Relative: In 936 years
```

It is an open bug in MYSql community. Please check the below URL for reference.
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,385047,385132#msg-385132

MySQL database's built-in functions like UNIX_TIMESTAMP() will return 0 after 03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038. (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: This query is regarding Hive and not MySQL. And @Pinaki already answered the question.